# Trying to optimize algorithm for percentage of certain color in canvas

Tags: jquery, html, optimization, canvas

I have the following little tidbit of code that I'm using to determine the percentage of color on a canvas, in this case the color is transparent which the imageData.data returns as [0,0,0,0]

Since I return this percentage on a mouseove, it's quite expensive to run, trying to optimize it.  Also keep in mind the color of the canvas is constantly changing so I need to grab the imageData each time and iterate it through it.

The bottleneck is all in the scratchPercentage function of course, I need a way to optimize this for instance only get new changes and not run through all the image data each time.

```
scratchFunc: function(e, $this, event)
{
    e.pageX = Math.floor(e.pageX - $this.canvas_offset.left);
    e.pageY = Math.floor(e.pageY - $this.canvas_offset.top);

    $this['scratch' + event](e, $this);

    if($this.settings['scratch' + event])
        $this.settings['scratch' + event](e, $this.scratchPercentage($this));
},

scratchPercentage: function($this)
{
    var hits = 0;
    var imageData = $this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,$this.canvas.width,$this.canvas.height)

    for(var i=0, ii=imageData.data.length; i<ii; i=i+4)
    {
        if(
            imageData.data[i] == 0 &&
            imageData.data[i+1] == 0 &&
            imageData.data[i+2] == 0 &&
            imageData.data[i+3] == 0
        ) hits++;
    }

    return hits / ($this.pixels) * 100;
},
```

Comment: Can you put example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Start with this modification:

```
scratchPercentage: function($this)
{
    var hits = 0;
    var imageData = $this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,$this.canvas.width,$this.canvas.height).data
    var pixels = imageData.length;

    for(var i=0, ii=pixels; i<ii; i=i+4)
    {
        if(
            imageData[i] == 0 &&
            imageData[i+1] == 0 &&
            imageData[i+2] == 0 &&
            imageData[i+3] == 0
        ) hits++;
    }

    return hits / ($this.pixels) * 100;
}
```

I don't have the reference link handy for this, but maintaining a handle to your canvas data array saves your loop having to resolve the location of the pixel data at every iteration. This actually results in a significant performance boost. Similarly, though not as important, you can also assign a variable to the size of your array so you don't have to resolve the value after each loop iteration.

Aside from these two changes, I don't think you can make `scratchPercentage()` any leaner. Without knowing the details of how your canvas is changing from frame to frame, I can't really suggest any optimizations for only calculating changes. Depending on your accuracy needs, you might consider checking every other pixel.

I can think of a rough WebGL solution to this as well, but it would not be straight-forward. Ultimately, if you don't have any consistent information about what has changed between the current and previous frames, you won't really be able to pre-calculate this percentage or significantly speed it up.

**Edit:** Depending on your canvas size, you could try resizing a copy of it in memory to 50% and doing your calculations on that. It won't be perfect, but it should be relatively accurate.

Answer (score 1):

1) Decrease sample rate.

Don't call the calculations each time mousemove event occurs but rather save the mouseX, mouseY and then call a sample function in `setInterval` (experiment with interval value - where the 100% accurate and safe value is interval of your rendering loop)

or use some kind of throttle function like in http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle

2) If this function doesn't have to be super accurate skip some pixels

let's say every 2nd `for (...; i = i + 8)`